# How SUM with autocomplete WHEN-clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table like

```
munic | origin  | date       | hour     | presence 
9875  | Germany | 2016-10-08 | 15:00:00 | 56
9875  | French  | 2016-10-08 | 18:00:00 | 24
9875  | Italians| 2016-10-08 | 18:00:00 | 6
```

With SUM I can sum value based on some conditions like:

```
SELECT munic, 
       SUM(presence) FILTER (WHERE origin = 'Germany' AND date = '2016-10-08' AND hour = '15:00:00') AS "Germany_2016-10-08_15:00:00"
```

The problem is that I have to sum the value in the column *presence* but based on too many condition based on 3 fields like below (8 days x 8 hours block x 12 country = 768 combinations), too much filter clause to be written by keyboard. The idea is to obtain a specific sum for every combination of the three fields in a news table.
Instead of writing every single filter clause is there a method that select automatically the combinations based on a general rule?

Then the second problem is in the new table, how to name each new column with something like a concatenation of the value of the three fields used for the sum.

The result can be:

```
   munic | Germany_2016-10-08_15:00:00 | French_2016-10-08_18:00:00 | Italians_2016-10-08_18:00:00
 9875    |    54                      |      24           |       6
```

Comment: SQL requires that the number, names and types of all columns of a select statement is known **before** the statement is executed. So what you are asking for is essentially impossible. It would however be easy to create multiple rows where each row is one combination and then do the some on them. The result of that can easily be transposed (aka "Pivot") using some front end tool.

Comment: SQL and rows of normal fields aren't going to work for this task. You can either build that data programatically, or perhaps output a JSON object. Are you open to any of that? What language are you using to code your program in?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd start by getting all of this data summed and named using rows instead of columns. You can include an (optional) where clause to get

```
 SELECT munic, origin, date, hour, sum(presence) 
  from my_tab
  /*OPTIONAL where clause to limit to specific countries, origins, dates, hours*/
  WHERE origin in ('Germany','Italy','France',....)
   and date in ('2016-10-08','2016-10-09',...)
  group by munic, origin, date, hour
```

With the query as written above, you're going to get the data you need, in row (not column) form. Additionally, you're going to NOT get "blank" rows where data does not exist. Example: If "Germany" has no row for 2016-10-08 18:00:00, then it simply will not exist. If you need that data, you'll have to come up with a way to generate the blank rows. One way of doing that is to have a Table, view or subquery that simply returns the name of each country.. then have another that returns each time period, and another that returns each date. Then you OUTER JOIN to each of these tables which will help generate your "blank rows".

Furthermore, it goes without saying that your dates, hours, or country list may need to change in the future (example: You're running '2016-10-08' right now, but you may want other date(s) the next time you run this query, so an additional concern is how to make this query not need a ton of edits every time you run the "report" differently.

That much of the issue will be up to you to determine what makes the most sense (are we limiting the data at all, or just getting ALL.. are the dates queried based off a "start date" + X years, etc... ) With the info you've provided, it's hard to say what would help in that regard.

After this initial process of "getting the data in row format" is complete, now you're going to have to do your "pivot" to switch the rows to columns... As stated before, this is not something SQL does natively or easily. Easiest solution is to use a NON-SQL solution to reform your data into an array, object, or other form using app code. Of course, this could also be done using pl/PGSQL or another DB language, or alternatively, could (with much effort) be reformed in SQL to return JSON data in the format you're wanting. Of course, your app will still need to interpret the JSON properly, which logically leads to the conclusion that if you can write app code, you should do what's easiest.... and the easiest solution would be to "Group/SUM" the data in SQL, then loop through it and build your final data set in app code.